# How to parse xml using different parent nodes in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-xml

In my xml file I have two or more parent nodes like:-

> //parent node pizza  
>       //attributes are 1 Veg Pizza
>       //parent node burger 
>       //attributes are 1 Veg Burger,

Whenever the user clicks on pizza `listview` item then the user should be able to view only list of pizza items in another activity's `listview`. I know how to call next activity and so on, but I want to know how I can use different parent nodes in my java class, exactly what are the changes I need to do in my java class, please see this link, I am using this tutorial, but here they are using only one parent node song but I want to add more and I have added in my xml file but don't know what are the changes I need to do in java class.

Comment: I recommend you try and format your question in a more readable fashion. Also, if you can give an example xml file (preferably one that is simple and stripped to the basics so we can easily understand your problem) that would help.

Comment: For different patent nodes you just follow this example: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782210/java-dom-xml-parsing-how-to-walk-through-multiple-node-levels

Comment: i have changed please read and revert me...

Answer (score 0):

```
carrier.xml ile contains below xml contents
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<carrier>
    <vehicle>
        <vehicle
            cid="1"
            cname="TAXI" />
        <vehivle
            cid="0"
            cname="AUTO" />
   </vehicle>
```

```
// In your code 
XmlPullParser xpp=null;
int eventType = 0;
XmlPullParserFactory factory =null;
BufferedReader bufr=null;   
StringBuilder total ="";
     try{           
    bufr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/carrier.xml"));
    total = new StringBuilder();
    String line=""; 
    while ((line = bufr.readLine()) != null)
    {     
    total.append(line);
    }                       
    factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();  
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);   
    xpp = factory.newPullParser();   
    xpp.setInput(new StringReader(new String(total)));                  
    eventType = xpp.getEventType();             
    }catch(XmlPullParserException e){
    // Log.v("xmlpullparser"," "+e);
    e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException ie){
    // Log.v("IOException"," "+ie);
    ie.printStackTrace();
    }


    try{
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){                    
    if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){ 
    String Scid="",Scname="";
    int acount=xpp.getAttributeCount();             
    if(acount!=-1){
    for(int x=0;x<acount;x++){                                              
                        if(xpp.getAttributeName(x).equalsIgnoreCase("cid")){
                            Scid=xpp.getAttributeValue(x);                                                                                  
                        }if(xpp.getAttributeName(x).equals("cname")){
                            Scname=xpp.getAttributeValue(x);
                        }
                    }               
    }   
    }       
    eventType = xpp.next();  
    }                               
    }catch(Exception e){        
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

After this you can use the Scid Scname etc in your code as per your convenience
```

Comment: meher, like here you are using only one parent node but i need to use multiple parent nodes which is different with each other like:- vehicle, transport (parent nodes)

Comment: hi, here xml pull parser will read all the start tags with same name or different I have specified the attributes string names like cid and cname and not the start tag String names.If you add log and print the start tag names by reading it in a string you will see all the start nodes. Hope I am clear to you.